# Grouping Array Items Based on Common String

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have the following code which grabs two separate arrays, flips the surname and firstname (also removes the comma) and outputs this:

> Director: Bert & Bertie
>
> Writer: Bert & Bertie
>
> Producer: Louise Knight
>
> Producer: Miles Wilkes
>
> Producer: Andy Welch
>
> Actor: Craig Parkinson
>
> Actor: Camilla Rutherford
>
> Actor: Paul Bhattarcharjee
>
> Actor: Ford Kieman
>
> Actor: Maurren the Pug
>
> Actor: Hannah Walters
>
> DP: Lynda Hall
>
> Cut: Matt Chodan

What I need to do is to group similar groups to output something like this:

> Director: Bert & Bertie
>
> Writer: Bert & Bertie
>
> Producer: Louise Knight, Miles Wilkes, Andy Welch
>
> Actors: Craig Parkinson, Camilla Rutherford, Paul Bhattarcharjee, Ford Kieman, Maurren the Pug, Hannah Walters
>
> DP: Lynda Hall
>
> Cut: Matt Chodan

Current PHP Code:

```
<?php 
$arrayname=explode(":::",$dwzXmlRec_1->GetFieldValue("PERSON_NAME"));
$arraynamel=count($arrayname);
$arrayrole=explode(":::",$dwzXmlRec_1->GetFieldValue("PERSON_FUNCTION"));   
$arrayrolel=count($arrayrole);

$name = "Lastname, Firstname"; 
$names = explode(", ", $name); 
$name = $names[1] . " " . $names[0]; 

for($i=0;$i<$arrayrolel;$i++) 
    { 
        $names = explode(", ", $arrayname[$i]); 
        $name = $names[1] . " " . $names[0];
        echo $arrayrole[$i].': '.$name.'<br />';
    } 
?>
```

UPDATE: Just one question, the data is set from an xml node, and since it's in array "as" is One role comes before another. For Example, 'Actor' comes first, then 'Director'. Is there any easy method to reverse it, so that Director comes first then Cast? I have added code to hide the unwanted roles/peoples see below:

```
// print out the list of people in each role
foreach($roles as $rolename => $people) {
    if ($rolename!="Cut" && $rolename!="Producer" && $rolename!="DP" && $rolename!="Writer"){
        if($rolename=="Actor") { $rolename="Cast";};
        echo $rolename . ": " . implode(", ", $people) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the role names are known ahead of time, you could put the role names in a numeric array and iterate over that, pulling out only the role names you want to display, in the order you want to display them.  Something like `$displayRoles = array("Director", "Producer", "Actor", ...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build an array that maps role names to an array of people who filled that role.  Possibly something like this:

```
$roles = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $arrayrole1; $i++) {
    $names = explode(", ", $arrayname[$i]);
    $name = $names[1] . " " . $names[0];
    // append the name to the array of people filling the role
    $roles[$arrayrole[$i]][] = $name; 
}

// print out the list of people in each role
foreach($roles as $rolename => $people) {
    echo $rolename . ": " . implode(", ", $people) . "<br />";
}
```